# How to fix vibration delay in android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, onclicklistener, vibration

I am using the following code to vibrate the device programmatically on a button click and it works but the vibration is not so quick as compared to my android device's default keyboard button press vibration. When I click the button in my android app the vibration takes a few milli seconds to start (making the app UI ugly). While vibration with typing on android default keyboard is quicker. So is it normal or it can be fixed somehow so that device vibration is quicker like its own keyboard vibration.

```
    int n;
        int n1;
private Vibrator vib;
        vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot((int)n, (int)n1));
```

Comment: Are you calling `getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);` for each button push?

Comment: No i call it only once in onCreate()

Comment: Are you calling `VibrationEffect.createOneShot((int)n, (int)n1)` for each button click? or are you storing the VibrationEffect and reusing it? I don't know if it becomes invalidated once its done, but creating involves quite a lot of operations.

Comment: Yes I call this one on each button click. I have not attempted to store it and reuse. Am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure but you could try to reuse it (ie only create it once), if it doesn't work after "one shot" then you could try one of the "prebaked" vibrations `VibrationEffect.get(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK);` which may get created faster.

Comment: I tried this vib.vibrate(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK); but the now there is no vibration with button click.

Comment: did you do this `vib.vibrate(VibrationEffect.get(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK));`  or `vib.vibrate(VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK);` because the second is wrong.